# Pandas group and sum values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

This ist my example Table imported from a CSV

```
Name    hours   work
User1   2       Kiwi
User1   5       Melon
...
User1   3       Kiwi
```

And this is my desired output:

```
Total Kiwi:  
User1   5
```

I guess it is possible with a right join or a groupby. But I cant relize it to real code. 
I tried something like this

```
ou = pd.DataFrame([[ou["work"].sum()["kiwi"]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','work'])['hours'].sum().unstack()
print (df)
work   Kiwi  Melon
Name              
User1     5      5
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='work', values='hours', aggfunc='sum')
print (df)

work   Kiwi  Melon
Name              
User1     5      5
```

And then:

```
print (df[['Kiwi']])
work   Kiwi
Name       
User1     5
```

Comment: I get  self.lift = 1 if -1 in self.index.labels[self.level] else 0
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'  but if I delete the .unstack() I dont get any errors but also no values.

Comment: Okay fixed it by myself the Pivot Table works thank you!